# How can I get a stereo Bluetooth signal converted to a mono one?

Tags: speakers, amplifier, diy

I am trying to build a small singe driver full range active bluetooth speaker using some of those cheap class D amplifier boards you can buy everywhere on eBay etc. Many of them comes with a build in Bluetooth receiver too (e.g. https://www.ebay.com/itm/Digital-Amplifier-TPA3116D2-100W-2-120W-Wireless-Bluetooth-4-0-Audio-Receiver/163463699345) , but, they are of cause all stereo as far as I can find. Now my speaker design only allows 1 driver, so I fear missing out on parts of the music "picture" in a stereo signal, if I e.g. only wired the left channel. So my question is: What would be the easiest way to obtain the full audio experience in a singe driver setup via Bluetooth?

Some of the ideas I have thought about are:

- that there maybe is a board doing exactly this, after all there are many single driver bluetooth speakers on the market..?
- that I maybe need two different board, one for Bluetooth signal one for mono amp?
- that I need to modify a board?
- that I can find a small 4 inch driver that would somehow play a stereo signal?

Answer (score 0):

Just bridge the output of the amplifier to the input of the speaker. Just bear in mind that the amplifier will be working at 240W instead of 120W per channel.